# I don't understand `cin` works in c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and I want learn how the following code generates output?

```
int main(){
    int a;
    char b;
    cin>>a; 
    cin>>b;
    cout<<a<<b;
}
```

I input `123` for `a` and `,` for `b`. But how come the line `cout<<a<<b` give output of `123,`?

Comment: Looks correct to me. What output do you think you should get?

Comment: How does cin work here

Comment: After your input a is 123 and b is a comma. Then you output the same. I really don't understand why you think it should be any different. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @john, why does `char b[] = {}`; instead of `char b;` affects `cout<<a;`?

Comment: @iGian Your version has undefined behaviour because you are reading input into an empty array.

Comment: @john, thanks. Still stuck. Actually, if I use `int a;` and `char b[] = "b";` then input just one char to `cin >> b;`, the `cout<<a;` is correct. While I input more than one char (`"bb"`) to `cin>>b`, the `cout<<b;` is correct (`"bb"`), but the `cout>>a;` is not. I'd expect `cout<<b;` to be wrong, but the unexpected output is `cout<<a;`. If a swap the variables declaration, declaring `char b[] = "b";` before `int a;` everything works as expected. Kinda backward override of `a` by the excess of `b` chars? I googled but not any hint to understand. Maybe you can point me to some resources?

Comment: @iGian You might be right about a backwards override but the only C++ answer is that it's undefined behaviour. Incidentally you need one more character in the array than characters input because `cin>>b` adds a terminating nul character to the array as well as the input characters.

Comment: @iGian For resources try googling 'buffer overflow'

Answer (score 1):

In `cin>>a>>b` when you enter 123, `a` is an integer, c++ starts to find an integer. It detects 123 but `,` isn't an integer so `cin` fails to detect this. When a `cin` fails it goes to the next command and the next command is to read a character `b` and it reads `,`.
I hope this was helpful!

Answer (score -1):

This happening because you have two different data types declared as "a" is type "int" while "b" is type "char" and moreover C++ takes '123' as single int-input. Hope this helps.
Quick Fix:
Avoid Char Input after int as when you press return (enter-key) char is inputted to it's ascii-value. 
**Code Snippet**:

```
int a;
char b;
cin>>a;
cout<<a<<endl;
cin>>b;
cout<<b<<endl;
```

Comment: `cin>>b` skips whitespace so b will be the next non-whitespace character after 123. It won't be the ASCII value of the enter key.

Comment: "op" stands for what??

Comment: @AliAsadullah Original Poster

Comment: You are right @Ali Asadullah, It should print 123 then char as the input sequence is little confusing here.